# Read a text file line by line into strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, line

How do I read the contents of a text file line by line into `String` without using a `BufferedReader`?

For example, I have a text file that looks like this inside:

```
Purlplemonkeys
greenGorilla
```

I would want to create two `strings`, then use something like this

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\Textfile.txt");
String str = new String(file.nextLine());
String str2 = new String(file.nextLine());
```

That way it assigns `str` the value of `"Purlplemonkeys"`, and `str2` the value of `"greenGorilla"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an `ArrayList`.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(input.nextLine());
}
```

Then you can access to one specific element of your list from its index as next:

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

which will give you the first line (ie: Purlplemonkeys)

Comment: You don't need to know it's an ArrayList. Coding `List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();` is cleaner

Comment: I'm using Eclipse.

 Next to `arrayList.add(Input.nextLine());` there is an error that says  `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - implements 
  java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected`

and next to `File file = new File(fileName);` there is an error that says `fileName cannot be resolved to a variable` 

This also causes errors in other parts of my class.

Comment: Also, where do I put the path leading to the txt file?

Comment: You put the filepath where `fileName` is. Like this: `File file = new File("ThisIsYourFilePath.txt");`

Answer (score 8):

You can read text file to list:

```
List<String> lst = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\test.txt"));
```

and then access each line as you want

P.S. Files - java.nio.file.Files

Answer (score 3):

If you use Java 7 or later

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(fileName).toPath());

for(String line : lines){
   // Do whatever you want
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: My personal favorite approach :)

Comment: The method readAllLines(Path) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Answer (score 2):

Sinse JDK 7 is quite easy to read a file into lines:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("text.txt").toPath())

String p1 = lines.get(0);
String p2 = lines.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
List<String> lines = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readLines(new FileReader(file));

//Direct access if enough lines read
if(lines.size() > 2) {
  String line1 = lines.get(0);
  String line2 = lines.get(1);
}

//Iterate over all lines
for(String line : lines) {
  //Do something with lines
}

//Using Lambdas
list.forEach(line -> {
  //Do something with line
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apache.commons.io.LineIterator`

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
 try {
   while (it.hasNext()) {
     String line = it.nextLine();
     // do something with line
   }
 } finally {
   it.close();
 }
```

One can also validate line by overriding `boolean isValidLine(String line)` method.
[refer doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: I don't think thats what he was looking for. `line` will be overwritten every time so its kind of pointless to even declare it. Why not just `println(input.nextLine())` ? `String line = ...` is kind of redundant.