# How to store information from a file into variables?

Tags: java

This is a part of an assignment that I have been having some trouble on.From my googling, I think I have to split the array and I have gotten to the point where I am now.

The program reads over a text file and outputs the text in it to the console. It then asks the user to input a name relating to the text file.
It then reads the file over again and what is suppose to happen next is for the variable power to store a number from a text file based on their input.

When I run my code, the text file outputs and it asks for the input. Then nothing happens; what should happen is that my variable power should output the value in index 2 of my array named g which should be 10 based on my text file.

My text file is organized like this:

Giant

Power

10

I want my int power to store 10 and I think that would be in index 2.
and Character (variable) is what the name that they enter in when being asked, in this case, Giant.

Am a beginner to java and any help is appreciated.

Edit: for now this problem is solved, dont know if it works or not because as I 'fixed' this problem an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 2 has occurred. Any ideas why?? This error is at line 46 which is int power = Integer.parseInt(g[2]);

```
while ((line = creatureRead.readLine()) != null)
{
  String[] g = line.split(" ");
  for (int index = 0; index < g.length; index++)
  {

    if (character.equals("Giant"))
    {
    int power = Integer.parseInt(g[2]);
    System.out.println(power);
    }
  }
      creatureRead.close(); 
}
}

catch (IOException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is how your program works:

1. Read the file and display its content to the console in form of 
    
   [Creature] Power [Power value]
2. User inputs [Creature]
3. Program is supposed to display [Power value] for that creature

My guess is that you got to end of file that's why you can't read from it. After 1) close your file and open it in 3). Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: I think you are right, that I have to close it and once a do that I closed the stream and no longer can re-read my file again. How can I 'open' the stream or re-read my file?

Comment: fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
   br = new BufferedReader(fr);

   String sCurrentLine;

   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }
   
   br.close();
   
   //open once more
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }

Comment: Thanks, but now there is an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question [Read a text file line by line into strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208962/java-read-a-text-file-by-line-into-a-string), the solution was simple:

```
List<String> lst = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\test.txt"));
```

and you can access the values very similarly to the way you access array values:

```
lst.get(0); //Creature
lst.get(1); //Power
lst.get(2); //10
```