# How to get String array using Files.list()

Tags: java, string, file-io, java-stream, java-nio

I have a **txt file** with strings.

I want to get a `String` array containing all lines from the file via `Files.list(Paths.get("path"))` method.

I tried to use `toArray()` but it returns an array of *paths* to files in "path" directory

How can I get it using `Files.list(Paths.get("path"))` (it's mandatory)?

I have something like this:

```
public Object[] returnStrings(){
    Object[] strings;
    try {
        strings = Files.list(Paths.get(path)).toArray();
    }catch (IOException ex){
        return null;
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: "I want to get String array" containing what? Content of that file? Please [edit] your question to clarify it. Also is `Files.list(Paths.get("path"))` mandatory? `Files.readAllLines(filePath, charset)` would create List<String> containing all lines from specified file, or if you really want to create String[] *array* you can use something like `File.lines(filePath, charset).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Files.list()` expects a *path* pointing to the *directory* as a parameter, and it'll give you a *stream* of `Path` objects (*if any*) contained in this directory. In case if the given *path* will be a *file*, you will get a `NotDirectoryException` exception. You can't access the *contents of a file* with `Files.list()`, it's simply meant for another purpose.

In order to **read** from the *text file* you can use either [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) or [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Contrary to `Files.readAllLines()` which dumps all file content into memory, the stream produced by `Files.lines()` will be populated lazily. Hence, in a general case `Files.lines()` a preferred way to read from a file, especially when you're unaware of it's size.

For this task, even though all file's content has to be allocated in the memory (*i.e. in this case the mentioned above upper-hand of a stream's laziness isn't important*), `Files.lines()` is a better choice because the expected result needs to be an *array of strings*. It will be both more performant and more space-efficient to generate an *array* as a result of execution of the stream pipeline, rather than reading the file into a *list* (which `readAllLines()` returns) and then creating a string array based on this list.

With `Files.lines()` it could be implemented like that:

```
public static String[] readFromFile(Path path) {
    String[] result;
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)) {
        result = stream.toArray(String[]::new);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = new String[0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

There are several **important issues** in your code:

- You are not closing the resource. Because stream is accessing the file, it has to be closed either explicitly inside the `finally` block or by using [**try with resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), as shown above (which preferred and more concise way).
- It not a good idea to store `String` in the array of `Object`s because in order to do anything with these strings apart from printing them you will have to do an unsafe type casting.
- It not very nice to return `null` in case when attempt to read from the file fails. Because `null` can a cause a problem afterwards when it'll not be obvious where it came from.

And lastly, a few **recommendations**:

- Avoid placing the *return* statement inside the `try` and `catch` blocks, it reduces readability.
- `List` is more convent and flexible container of data than array. In cases when you are not dealing with an existing code that expects an array, use `List` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily with functional programming. Use a StringBuffer to add the paths in the recursive loop :

```
    StringBuffer strList = new StringBuffer();
    Files.list(Paths.get(".")).forEach(s -> strList.append(s));
    System.out.println(strList);
```